# Change checkbox tick color and icon - sapui5

Tags: css, checkbox, sapui5

I need to change the color of the tick on a UI5 checkbox.
I've looked at the CSS and found out that this is in the `::before` selector:

[image]

I've added a class to the checkbox, called `.accept` and defined like this on the CSS file:

```css
.accept.sapMCbBg.sapMCbMarkChecked::before{
    content: "\e05b";
    font-family: "SAP-icons";
    color: #00a600;
}
```

This is not working. Do you have any suggestion?
Thank you.

EDIT: Here's the code for the checkbox:

```js
var oCheckBox = new sap.m.CheckBox({
  text: "test",
  selected: false,
  select: function(oEvent){
    if (oEvent.getSource().getSelected() == true){
      oEvent.getSource().addStyleClass("accept");
    }else{
      oEvent.getSource().removeStyleClass("accept");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: For readers using UI5 1.38 and above, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62162162/5846045. Avoid custom CSS for displaying semantic colors / states.

Comment: Please consider to accept the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62162162/5846045) to help future readers finding the latest solution. Manipulating CheckBox with custom CSS and jQuery should be avoided!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add new `CSS` class to `CheckBox` DOM once it is rendered. You can get respective `DOM` element with `getDomRef`, which gives you `HTML DOM` for the `UI5` element on which it is invoked.

```
.green::before{
    color: #00a600 !important;
}
```

Then, get into the CheckBox's *tick* div which is the first child of obtained `DOM` with jQuery [`children`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method.

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
    var cb = this.getView().byId("cb");
    $($(cb.getDomRef()).children()[0]).addClass("green");
}
```

[Here](https://jsbin.com/qudowo/edit?css,js,output) is working example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are some predefined set of checkboxes is given in UI5 where as display color is changed based on `ValueState`.

**Output:-**

[image]

**Code-**

```
// create CheckBoxes in different states
var oLayout = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout("matrix1");
    oLayout.setLayoutFixed(false);
    oLayout.setColumns(4);

var oCB1 = new sap.ui.commons.CheckBox({
    text : 'error',
    tooltip : 'Select for Error',
    valueState : sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error
    });

var oCB2 = new sap.ui.commons.CheckBox({
    text : 'warning',
    tooltip : 'Select for Warning',
    valueState : sap.ui.core.ValueState.Warning
    });

var oCB3 = new sap.ui.commons.CheckBox({
    text : 'ReadOnly',
    tooltip : 'This CheckBox is read only',
    editable : false,
    checked : true
    });

var oCB4 = new sap.ui.commons.CheckBox({
    text : 'disabled',
    tooltip : 'This CheckBox is disabled',
    enabled : false
    });

oLayout.createRow(oCB1, oCB2, oCB3, oCB4);

// attach it to some element in the page
oLayout.placeAt("sample2");
```

Options of value state - 
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.ValueState

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Comment: This could solve my problem, but I'm using sap.m library (v.1.28, valueState is only available for v.1.38) and sap.ui.commons checkboxes are way too small (and finding the right place to change the size is a nightmare). But thanks anyway, if I can't get to the right spot, I'll use this option.

Answer (score 0):

Since UI5 1.38, a [`valueState`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.ValueState) can be assigned to `sap.m.CheckBox`:

```xml
<CheckBox valueState="Success" />
```

Currently, four value states / semantic colors are supported:

[image]

From: https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.m.CheckBox/sample/sap.m.sample.CheckBox